# Correct memory management for struct

Tags: c++

I want to be sure that no memory leak takes place.

```
   struct tStruct{
       uint32_t id;
       A* a;
       C b;
   };
   std::vector<tStruct*> m_vector;
```

I push and erase objects into vector following way.

Pushing :

```
tStruct* myStruct = new tStruct;
myStruct->id = ID; // Some unique value
myStruct->a= new A();
myStruct->b = c; // c is an object
m_vector.push_back(myStruct);
```

Erasing :

```
 // Some stuff here 
 for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_vector.size(); i++) {
     if (m_vector.at(i)->id == ID) { // Some filtering
         delete m_vector.at(i);
         m_vector.erase(m_vector.begin() + i);
     }
 }
```

Do i understand correctly that

1. I need to delete myStruct->a explicitely as it is alloced in heap ?
2. For the other members, they will be deleted automatically as they are in stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually delete all dynamically allocated objects which are created by `new operator`. Otherwise you have potential memory leak, as you haven't deleted `A* a;`

`new` and `delete`, `new []` and `delete []` should always be used in pair.

Better solution is to use smart pointers:

```
struct tStruct
{
     uint32_t id;
     std::unique_ptr<A> a;
     C b;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<tStruct>> m_vector;
```

Use [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove items from vector:

```
m_vector.erase(std::remove_if(m_vector.begin(), m_vector.end(), 
               [](std::unique_ptr<tStruct>& up){ return up->id == ID; }), 
               m_vector.end());
```

Comment: No, better solution: _stop with all the dang pointers!_ There's no evidence in the question that dynamic allocation is required at all.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: If you have a `new` you must have a corresponding `delete`. Same with malloc and free in C.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you create an object in the heap using `new`, there must be a corresponding `delete` somewhere. Otherwise you will be leaking resources (memory, in this case).

But, generally speaking (and this applies to your example), the best that you can do is using an auxiliary class to manage those resources. In your case, a smart pointer. In C++11 the standard library offers `std::shared_ptr<>` which looks like the right smart pointer for your case:

```
struct tStruct{
    uint32_t id;
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    C b;
};
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<tStruct>> m_vector;
```

Creating a smart pointer is not too different from creating a raw pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<tStruct> myStruct (new tStruct);
myStruct->id = ID; // Some unique value
myStruct->a.reset(new A());
myStruct->b = c; // c is an object
m_vector.push_back(myStruct);
```

But now you can forget about calling `delete` because `std::shared_ptr<>` will take care of that:

```
// Some stuff here 
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_vector.size(); i++) {
    if (m_vector.at(i)->id == ID) { // Some filtering
        // delete m_vector.at(i); This is no longer needed
        m_vector.erase(m_vector.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code still contains several memory leaks. Your pushing code does not have any roll-back for if pushing the object fails:

```
tStruct* myStruct = new tStruct;
myStruct->id = ID;
myStruct->a= new A(); //could throw, if it does, then `myStruct` will leak
myStruct->b = c; // c is an object
//could throw, if it does, then `myStruct` and `myStruct->a` will leak
m_vector.push_back(myStruct);
```

In general, any manual calls to `delete` indicates that your code either leaks or is overly complicated. To make the code not leak, you should use smart pointers:

```
 struct tStruct{
    uint32_t id;
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    C b;
};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<tStruct>> m_vector;
```

To construct:

```
std::unique_ptr<tStruct> myStruct(new tStruct);
myStruct->id = ID;
myStruct->a.reset(new A());
myStruct->b = c; // c is an object
m_vector.push_back(std::move(myStruct));
```

No special deletion code is needed.